# Redis: updating a cache while data is being fetched

Tags: redis, locking

I am using Redis as a cache to serve requests for a few end-points.

What's a standard way of "locking" down the cache, while it's being updated, so that the end-points reading the cache does not happen at the same time its been updated.
Do I need to have a "write" lock implemented on Redis.
All end points first check if the write lock is available, if so - they read the data, but when it's not available they don't use the cache, instead directly fetch it from the database?

The writer acquires the lock , waits for a pre-specified "delay" in order for current reads to finish, and then refreshes the cache, following which it releases the lock?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Redis manages the locking for simple command (SET, SETEX, GET, INCR and many many more), Go ahead and just use it.